# Cohomological dimension of closed $G$-invariant subspaces on homology manifolds with a group action

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, group-actions

Suppose  $G$  is a compact topological  group acting  on an $m$-homology  manifold $M$ over some  ring $R$  by homeomorphisms.

Assume  that  the  action  of  $G$ is effectively  finite on a closed $G$-invariant subspace $A$ such that $A$ does not  contain a  connected component of $M$.

(Recall  that  an  effectively  finite  action means that  the  quotient  group  of  $G$ by the  ineffective kernel $K$  is finite. In  the  case  I  am  interested,  one  can  assume $G/K \cong \mathbb{Z}/k$)

Does it follow  that $H^{m}(A/G,R)=0$?